# Getting all values from all table

Tags: excel, google-sheets

i couldn't ask my question very well. I put here a table that i want to create in google sheet, excel or other. Anyone can help me please?

| street name | number |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Impasse Malabane | 9 |  | Impasse Malabane | Impasse du Puech | Impasse Bimet | Rue Levers |
| Impasse du Puech | 1 bis |  | 9 | 1 bis | 6 | 26 |
| Rue Levers | 26 |  | 5 | 2 bis | 2 | 28 |
| Impasse Bimet | 6 |  | 8 | 1 |  |  |
| Impasse Bimet | 2 |  | 8 bis |  |  |  |
| Impasse Malabane | 5 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Impasse du Puech | 2 bis |  |  |  |  |  |
| Impasse Malabane | 8 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Impasse Malabane | 8 bis |  |  |  |  |  |
| Impasse du Puech | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Rue Levers | 28 |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: You should be able to do that using Power Query with either grouping or pivot technique. Post your code and describe any problems you run into.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets, assuming that your original headers "Street Name" and "Number" are in A1 and B1 (with the data in A2:B), place this in D2:

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(TRIM({UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),TO_TEXT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("| ",1,{IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""))&TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>""))),A2:A&B2:B,1,FALSE),UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),"")),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""))),1,1,0)})&"|","| 1|",0,1))),"|"))})))`

This one formula will generate all results. As you add new data in A2:B, it will be added without any need to edit the formula.

Answer (score 0):

This VBA script does it. Assuming your data starts in `A1` in `Sheet1`.

```vb
Sub transform()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim first_col As String: first_col = "A"
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim c_last As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim key As Variant
Dim arr() As String

Set c_last = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, first_col).End(xlUp)
For Each c In ws.Range(first_col & 2, c_last)
  If dict.Exists(Trim(c)) Then
    dict.Item(Trim(c)) = dict.Item(Trim(c)) & "$" & CStr(c.Offset(, 1))
  Else
    dict.Item(Trim(c)) = CStr(c.Offset(, 1))
  End If
Next

Set ws2 = ws.Parent.Sheets.Add(After:=ws.Parent.Worksheets(ws.Parent.Worksheets.Count))
Set c = ws2.Range("A1")
For Each key In dict.Keys()
  c = key
  arr = Split(dict.Item(key), "$")
  c.Offset(1).Resize(UBound(arr) + 1) = Application.Transpose(arr)
  Set c = c.Offset(, 1)
Next

End Sub
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Google Apps Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  // initialize
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var values = ss.getRange(2,1,lr-1,2).getValues();
  console.log(values.sort());
  var result = [];
  console.log(result);
  var prevCol = '';

  // populate array
  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] != prevCol) {
      result.push([values[i][0], values[i][1]]);
    }
    else {
      result[result.length-1].push(values[i][1]);
    }
    prevCol = values[i][0];
  }
  console.log(result);

  // transpose array
  var newArray = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
      newArray.push([]);
  };

  for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < result.length; j++){
      newArray[j].push(result[i][j]);
    };
  };

  // write to range

  var dest = ss.getRange(2,4,newArray[0].length,newArray.length);
  dest.setValues(newArray);
}
```

Comment: Your code is usefull, nevertheless, the length of each "branch" is not always the same and the original array is "unregular". In this case, there is a lack of one address (Malabane, #9). I propose to complete the array by empty string when the value is null then transpose and write in range.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to understand the question, but I think you are trying to convert a 2-column table into a multi-column table with data.

You can do this with an array formula. First, copy all your distinct street names into a single row. In the picture below, this was done in cells F1:I1.

**Cell F2 formula:**

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9999, SMALL(IF($F$1=$A$2:$A$9999, ROW($A$2:$A$9999)-ROW($A$2)+1), ROW(1:1))),"")}
```

You need to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to get those curly brackets to make this an array formula. Drag it down as far as you need, well beyond as many rows as you would expect. It's wrapped in an IFERROR handler to show a blank if no more results are found.

The formulas for the other columns are similar. You just need to change the reference from $F$1 to $G$1 and so on, and also repeat the array trick.

Also, if you have more than 9999 rows, just adjust the end row number in the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A correction of Carlos' proposal (Google Sheets) :

```
function myFunction() {
  // initialize
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var values = ss.getRange(2,1,lr-1,2).getValues();
  values.sort();
  var result = [];
  var prevCol = '';

  // populate array
  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] != prevCol) {
      result.push([values[i][0], values[i][1]]);
    }
    else {
      result[result.length-1].push(values[i][1]);
    }
    prevCol = values[i][0];
  }
  // determine maximum length
  var max = 0 ;
  for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
      max=Math.max(max,result[i].length);
  };

  // complete the array by replacing null values with an empty string 
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i ++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < max; j ++) {
      if (result[i][j] == null) {result[i][j] = "";}
    }
  }

  // transpose array
  var result = transpose(result);
  
  // write to range
  ss.getRange(2,4,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result);
}

function transpose(a){
  return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function (c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
}
```